# searching for specific string on a received sms-android

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver

im a newbie when it comes to programming in java.
im trying to capture an sms from a specific number and search the said sms for a specific string like "Balance" and copy the next string to a variable.
the result would be like "Balance:100.00"

so far i can only capture the incoming sms using BroadcastReceiver

SMSReceiver:

```
public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{

    String origin, body;

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
  {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

    SmsMessage[] msgs = null;

    if (extras == null) return;

    Object[] pdus =  (Object[]) extras.get("pdus");

    msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
    for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++)
    {
        msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);

        // Original Address
        origin = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();

        // Message body
        if ("123".equals(origin))
        {
          body = msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
          Toast.makeText(context, body, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          abortBroadcast();
        }
        else
      abortBroadcast();

        break;
     }
  }    
}
```

is it possible if it is can anyone give me a guide on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your problem is as you don't actually say but this routine works for me to trap an incoming SMS.

```java
public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private SmsMessage[] getMessagesFromIntent(Intent intent) {
    SmsMessage retMsgs[] = null;
    Bundle bdl = intent.getExtras();
    try {
        Object pdus[] = (Object[]) bdl.get("pdus");
        retMsgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
        for (int n = 0; n < pdus.length; n++) {
            byte[] byteData = (byte[]) pdus[n];
            retMsgs[n] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu(byteData);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("GetMessages", "fail", e);
    }
    return retMsgs;
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String message;

    if (!intent.getAction().equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")) return;

    SmsMessage msg[] = getMessagesFromIntent(intent);

    // filter through all the messages
    for (int i = 0; i < msg.length; i++) {
        message = msg[i].getDisplayMessageBody();

                    // Do something with the message

        }
    }

}
}
```